# loss nan and constant accuracy while training titanic survivour problem with neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have done StandardScaler on training set, also I have tried different optimizers like adam, rmsprop. Tried with tweaking learning rates, changing number of layers. Tried number of activations like leakyrelu, tanh, but I always get the same result that is constant accuracy and loss as nan. This is my model could anyone help and tell me whats happening and where am I going wrong? I want to approach this problem with neural networks.

This is the dataset

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GG0J.jpg)

Code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu', input_dim=7), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(264, activation = 'relu'),    
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation = 'relu'),    
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(optimizer= sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 10)
```

Output:

```
Train on 891 samples
Epoch 1/10
891/891 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 2/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 271us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 3/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 268us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 4/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 288us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 5/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 269us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 6/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 262us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 7/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 270us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 8/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 268us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 9/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 271us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
Epoch 10/10
891/891 [==============================] - 0s 263us/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.6162
```

Comment: try to change the last activation function to ```softmax``` instead of ```sigmoid```

Comment: it still gives same result

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai this is not correct; with a single-node last layer and `binary_cross_entropy` loss, `sigmoid` is indeed the correct activation.

Comment: Get rid of all `Dropout` and `BatchNormalization` layers (which are *not* supposed to be used by default), and continue to experiment with the model architecture.

Comment: tried it too, same results..